# Convert multiple GeoJSON files to one Topojson while keeping respective properties

Tags: geojson, topojson

I'm trying to merge a country-level world geosjon file and a state-level us geojson file into one topojson file. I know how to use *--property* to keep certain properties when converting **one** geojson to topojson.

But since the **two** geojson files have different properties, how should I specify which properties of which file to keep? Such as keeping the "state" property from the US geojson and "country" property from the World geojosn.

I also find this command to merge geojson into one topojson, but this will either loose all properties from all files or keep all by adding the '-p'

*topojson input1.json input2.json -o output.json*

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/Command-Line-Reference), the `-p` flag takes the properties to keep as arguments, so in your case it would be

```
topojson input1.json input2.json -p state -o output.json
```

Comment: Thanks. But in this case, it will only keep the "state" property from input1.json (assuming that's the US geojson). Where should I specify to keep properties such as "country" from input2.json (World Geojon)

Comment: You can give the `-p` option multiple times or separate multiple properties with commas. This is all explained with examples in the documentation I've linked to.